# extreme newbie - hello world error

Tags: c++

Using B. Stroustrup's Programming text and the 'hello world' program about pg 50 gives errors. I have issues with the "std_lib_facilities.h" include file.

After running (as root) 'gcc hworld1.cpp' the output is -

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/hash_map:60,
             from std_lib_facilities.h:34,
             from hworld1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28: warning: #warning This file     includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
/tmp/ccpwXUYx.o: In function `main':
hworld1.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::cout'
hworld1.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char,     std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char>  >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/tmp/ccpwXUYx.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
hworld1.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
hworld1.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccpwXUYx.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

any suggestions how to fix the file, perhaps commenting out the hash portion?

Excited to finally have time to start, but this seems like a little larger than a 1st troubleshooting task. I have tried just using iostream as the include. I'm running this on Ubuntu 11.04. Perhaps I need to update gcc or use g++. Not sure what might ease me past this one. I tried a few things with 'using ... std' with the ... as the appropriate name I cannot recall (oops). Anyone just know the right includes.

here is the code -

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout<<"hiya people\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `g++` to compile and link C++.

Comment: @Mark: Stroustrup has [more than one book](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/).

Comment: Please don't do that as root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use g++, because gcc is C compiler (not C++).

Comment: This is true. Although gcc is a C++ compiler it just won't link with the stdlib automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<"hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That said but the book may want you to do it certain way for a reason. Those error are link time errors, after the code has been compiler it needs linking with other procompiled code along with the header file there should be a lib file. you need to add this as a compiler parameter.

EDIT: After further inspection it seems that the missing "link" is the standard library, which isn't surprising seeing as you are using gcc rather than g++ which will automatically link with the stdlib.

Comment: @Mat: yup that is the way I do it. I just Yanked and Pasted into my answer.

Comment: `endl` is not the same as `\n`, and you should not use it unless you actually want to flush the buffer. And flushing near exit is redundant.

Comment: I am aware of this, although I think in the case of a hello world you would want to flush the buffer. (Although I imagine that the buffer flushes in the streams destructor)

Comment: one of the point of Bjarne creating the special header file was a la Irge number of includes and other functions to work with the book. At some point, my addition of iostreams will not be sufficient, so if there is a more perm. workaround great. For now I can continue on...

Answer (score 1):

Use header file iostream and not the one you are using.

Also make sure you use g++ and not gcc. Since gcc is compiler for C and g++ is for C++